# Symfony validator translations

Tags: symfony

I just started using [symfony validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) and i really like it except translation part, currently it uses my own translator lib, but i found validator.LOCALE.xlf files where are [translations for almost all languages](https://github.com/symfony/validator/tree/master/Resources/translations) stored, and i can't figure out how to use them.

My current validator registering code is

```
$container->register('validator', \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface::class)
    ->setFactory(
        [
            new Reference('validator.builder'),
            'getValidator'
        ]
    );

$container->register('validator.builder', \Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilderInterface::class)
    ->setFactory(
        [
            \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation::class,
            'createValidatorBuilder'
        ]
    )
    ->addMethodCall(
        'setTranslator',
        [
            new Reference('translator') // Symfony translatorInterface
        ]
    )
    ->addMethodCall(
        'setTranslationDomain',
        [
            'messages'
        ]
    );
```

It looks like i checked already whole validator structure, like RecursiveValidator, ContextualValidator, Contexts and etc, but just somewhere missing one single param, on another hand [ConstraintViolationBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Violation/ConstraintViolationBuilder.php#L142) just simply takes passed translator and trying to translate constraint message through it, no attempts to use any xlf files.

Just force search through all validator library files gave no result too.

[Symfony guilde](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html) didn't helped too, because it offers to use default error sentences as a translation key, and use this "keys" in your own translations files, but why copy already translated sentences to your own file, and also create a mess with keys pattern (for example i use snake case) when there is already structured files exists (i am talking about .xlf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add xlf file loader to your translator, and pass it .xlf translations as a resource.

Something like that

```
$container->register('translator.xlf_file_loader', \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader::class);
$container->register('translator.php_file_loader', \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\PhpFileLoader::class);
$container->register('translator', \Project\Framework\Translation\Translator::class)
    ->addArgument(
        new Reference('service_container')
    )
    ->addMethodCall(
        'addLoader',
        [
            'php',
            new Reference('translator.php_file_loader')
        ]
    )
    ->addMethodCall(
        'addLoader',
        [
            'xlf',
            new Reference('translator.xlf_file_loader')
        ]
    )
    ->addMethodCall('addResource', ['php', __DIR__ . '/../translation/lt.php', 'lt'])
    ->addMethodCall('addResource', ['php', __DIR__ . '/../translation/en.php', 'en'])
    ->addMethodCall('addResource', ['php', __DIR__ . '/../translation/ru.php', 'ru'])

    ->addMethodCall('addResource', ['xlf', __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/symfony/validator/Resources/translations/validators.lt.xlf', 'lt'])
    ->addMethodCall(
        'setFallbackLocales',
        [
            ['lt']
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried to either

1. change the locale in the app configuration:

   `# config/packages/translation.yaml
   framework:
       default_locale: 'en'
       translator:
           fallbacks: ['en']`

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration)

2. change the locale based on (user) input:

   ```
   public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
      $request = $event->getRequest();

      // some logic to determine the $locale
      $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
   ```

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html)

Comment: ValidatorBuilder#L324 overwrites locale if no translator is set, but if it is, translator takes locale from request on his own, no need for additional code. So solution is just to pass additional translation resources, and translator will automatically translates everything.